# Binding custom class

Tags: silverlight, binding, datatemplate

Simple question about XAML.
There is a class Achievement and a control AchievementControl to display it.
I have tried to create a ListBox which contains List as ItemsSource and DataTemplate

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Achievements}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:AchievementControl Achievement="{Binding}" />
        </DataTeplate>
    </ListBix.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But as I can see in debugger it sends a System.Windows.Data.Binding object as a value to setter of Achievement property instead of Achievement object, so, execution fails.

Comment: You will have to assign Path property for Binding

Comment: Even when I use {Binding Path=.} it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your control that contains the AchievementControl has a DataContext set. Then make sure that DataContext has a Property (Example = MyAchievement)

```
<DataTemplate>
    <controls:AchievementControl Achievement="{Binding MyAchievement}" />
</DataTeplate>
```

Comment: I have a listbox, I want to bind to item of List<Achievement>.

Comment: OK. First of all make sure your List is an ObservableCollection (and implements INotify if need be). Then whatever your collection is called put that name in Achievement="{Binding CollectionName}"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind directly with the Achievement class then you need to override the 
**ToString()** method Or create a **value converter** or bind with the **properties** of your class.

Comment: What value converter from Achievement class to?

Comment: try pasting your xaml here. I want to see your datacontext

Comment: Okay, I added some xaml directly to the question.